# Why is Parse.Cloud.httpRequest failing non-deterministically on a cloud method?

Tags: parse-platform

I am doing a method where I am using 2 Parse.Cloud.httpRequest calls, with one being inside of the other. However, this method seem to fail with an alarming frequency. Like 1 in 5 tries, each time the error is:

Request failed with response code 500
 {"uuid":"bc75e304-8964-30f9-c9d5-92fabf02f624","status":500,"error":{"code":-1,"error":"Request timed out"},"headers":{},"text":"{\"code\":124,\"error\":\"Request timed out\"}","cookies":{}}

I looked up code 124, and it corresponds to

*Timeout    124 Error code indicating that the request timed out on the server. Typically this indicates that the request is too expensive to run.*

I am only running a couple REST requests per minute and the run of the method does not exceed 3 seconds. I checked the same calls via REST and there is never any problems.

What's the cause for this problem and can I fix it by upgrading my parse account?

Comment: I'd take the error at face value and consider that maybe the requests are more expensive than you think.

Comment: How can one REST request be more expensive than another REST request. Unless the opposing server times out. Which through CURL testing it never does. Please explain your logic?